# Referenced file contains errors (org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.3.xsd)

Tags: spring, maven, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-tool-suite

When I validate aplicationContext.xml file I get this error:

```
Referenced file contains errors (project-aware://pm-master/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.3.xsd).
```

and here is xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
     xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<jpa:repositories  base-package="com.jedlab.pm.dao"  entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

and spring data jpa version is 1.11.0.RELEASE.

When I remove the jpa:repositories line the error disappear.
How can I solve it?

Comment: sounds like a bug, either in the tooling or the xsd. Can you file a bug at: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide, and maybe refer to a sample project on GitHub that reproduces this error? That would be great and help a lot. Many many thanks!!!

Comment: When I removed the Maven's repository folder and built it again, the problem solved.

Comment: ah, great, glad you found a way to fix it. Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using eclipse then clearing cache from Windows-> Preferences -> Network Connections -> Cache will be helpful.